# ssh script to test if date>15 minutes

Tags: bash

Someone can help me write a small ssh script to test if file "/usr/modified.txt" has not been modified within 15 minutes, then start a command ./start.sh

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $date -gt 15 ]

then

/start.sh

fi
```

Comment: What do you mean with ssh script? Do you mean Bash script?

Comment: don't forget the `.` on that `./start`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(find /usr/modified.txt -mmin +15) ]]; then
   ./start.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the basic commands `date` and `stat`:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=`stat -c %Y /usr/modified.txt`
y=`date -d '15 min ago' +%s`

if ((x < y)); then
    /path/to/start.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

@Phil, not quite.

-mtime is for days.

-mmin is for minutes

remember of course that this is with GNU find, which ships with most Linux distros but not all tradional nixes.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer to the question.